# Twitter RSS feed

Tags: twitter, rss

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you find a Twitter RSS feed?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/15919/how-do-you-find-a-twitter-rss-feed)

How can you get an RSS feed of your own tweets from Twitter? [The official Twitter page](http://support.twitter.com/groups/31-twitter-basics/topics/111-features/articles/15361-how-to-find-your-rss-feed) says they no longer support it. What third-party feed software do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Google Reader to fetch RSS feeds from twitter. Just remove **#!** from https://twitter.com/#!/username and paste the URL in "Add a Subscription" field in Google Reader. In fact Google Reader will also give you the actual feed URL in form of https://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/xxxxxxxxx.rss if you click upon "Show Details" on the right side of feeds page.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an alternate location of RSS feeds in Twitter:

http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.rss?screen_name=labnol

Do replace "labnol" in the URL with your own Twitter screen name.

Comment: I tested it and this method worked fine on 2012-06-18.

Comment: This seems to be the current way, but it's going to be deprecated this month, see https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/11582

Comment: You can also use Google Scripts to create [RSS Feeds for Twitter](http://www.labnol.org/internet/twitter-rss-feeds/27931/)

Answer (score 2):

Construct the RSS URL as

```
http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/username.rss
```

where `username` is your Twitter username. I just tested it, and it works! I used [Opera's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera_%28web_browser%29) RSS feed reader (menu *Feeds*), but any RSS reader should do.

---

For example, for [Clay Shirky](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clay_Shirky) (http://twitter.com/cshirky) the RSS URL is

```
http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/cshirky.rss
```

---

As of 2012-06-18, it still works.

Comment: I hope that they have brought this feature back for good, then.  Check with @support on this, as it may not last for long.  Last time I sent them a DM, they said there wasn't any sanctioned way short of using the web widgets that they have now.  See [my question](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/18015/organizing-and-filtering-twitter-data) for some other `zeyne.net` entity that seems to also work for lists -- though I haven't been able to verify who that company is.