# Organizing and filtering Twitter data

Tags: webapp-rec

I follow a lot of people on Twitter, normally I use the web interface.  I used to follow a lot more, but a few months ago, I organized my follows into lists.

I ran into two problems, I ran out of lists quickly (I had far more than 20 categories to fill).  The problem is, now I'm not as diligent about opening up the lists and seeing the activity.

What **web application** options do I have "in the cloud" for keeping better track of my Twitter account?  Ideally, I'd love a way to filter list activity in real time (so if I enter "pizza" and either "@pizzaman" tweeted or someone tweeted about pizza, it would show up).

I realize that this could be perceived as a bit open ended, but despite searching through many options, I find a lot of lists of apps don't have ones with features that I'm looking for, and many are fly-by-night kind of things.  Most recently, I've tried HootSuite, but it seems to have more features if I want to keep track of my followers, rather than the people I follow.  I've tried other non-web apps in the past like Tweetdeck, but it didn't seem to do everything I wanted.

I'm definitely not asking someone to do the legwork for me, but I'd appreciate any recommendations.

Comment: Have you tried [Spaz](http://getspaz.com/)

Comment: @phwd No, I've never heard of it until now.  I will download it tonight and try it out.  Thanks.

Comment: @phwd I think it's marginally closer, but not quite there.  I'm going to keep looking at it, though.

Comment: @phwd I don't think that's going to do it.  It's got great potential, and I really like the search/filter for tweets, but it doesn't seem to be able to handle multiple lists at the same time.  Since it's open source, it's definitely extensible, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a RSS feed for your Twitter List using this service -
http://zeyne.net/rss.php?url=twitter.com/{username}/{List name}

*(replace the actual username & List name within the placeholders)*

Subscribe to the generated feed with Google Reader. Within Google Reader, you can then search for keywords within tweets from your Lists using Google Reader's Search feature.

Comment: It seems as though many of these services were shut down or they don't work anymore due to a change Twitter made in [May or so](http://www.staynalive.com/2011/05/twitter-and-facebook-both-quietly-kill.html).  There is a way to access lists via an officially sanctioned [Twitter Widget](http://twitter.com/about/resources/widgets/widget_list), so I may look into trying to get the info directly from that.

Comment: I've tried the zeyne.net service & it works.

Comment: Okay, it's passed that test for me, too. Do you know anything about the company itself? Also, naive question, since these are public lists, there should be no need for them to access my account in any way?

Comment: Do you have any further information on the company which provides this service?

Comment: No idea about the company, its probably an individual who has published it. The service doesn't seem to have any documentation and I figured the URL structure from an example.

Comment: Okay.  I had tweeted to them about it, so I'll see if they get back to me.  Thanks again for the tip!