# "Note in Reader" missing

Tags: rss, google-plus, google-reader

My father has a static website that he uses for political reasons. To add items to his RSS feed, he used to use the "Note in Reader" bookmarklet. Google Reader has been merged with Google+ and that feature no longer exists. Furthermore, it seems that it is no longer possible to share static pages on a Google Reader feed if they are not in the Google+ system.

Are there any ways I can get events added to the RSS feed again?

Comment: Looks like it's been superseded by the +1 tab of a Google Plus profile

Comment: A static site implies it's self-hosted somewhere. Migrate the site to a self-hosted blogging CMS.

Comment: I manage the site.  The main page content changes, so old blog posts virtually cease to exist because he replaces them.  What we had been doing was adding a new link to the homepage on his RSS feed with the comments being the content of the article.  The +1 button lets of share the post, but I can't get that shared item onto the original Shared Items feed.  That's what I need.

Comment: I'm hoping that the feature will make a reappearance; the data is still there: http://www.google.com/reader/view/user/-/state/com.google/created

Answer (score 1):

[Twitter provides a RSS feed for each account.](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/14795/twitter-rss-feed) You can consider posting each blog post title & its URL as a tweet. This way you can not only publicize the content over Twitter but also get a RSS feed.

Update: Consider using [Delicious](http://delicious.com). You can bookmark your own web pages to create a public feed.

Once you have their bookmarklet in the Bookmark bar of your favorite browser, you can click on it while you are on a new static page of your website that you want to add to the feed. If you select some text within the static page, the Delicious bookmarklet will set that as that page's description for the feed or you can write whatever text you like for the Description field.

Comment: That will not let me continue using the current feed or archive the content of each post. Both are necessary.

Comment: @Nathan Tornquist - true, this is only a workaround for a Google Reader feature that is taken off. If there aren't too many, you could post titles of old articles to Twitter as well. By subscribing to your own Twitter feed within Google Reader, you can archive it.

Comment: @NathanTornquist Consider using Delicious. See update above.

Comment: The solution ended up being to just rebuild the website. We're using WordPress now and have great feed support.